# Social Sharing and animated gifs with ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to share animated gifs throw Social Sharing native plugin in Ionic2. The problem is the animated gif is converted to static gif.

My function is this:

```
whatsappShare(url:string){
    console.log("Compartir por Whatsapp");
    SocialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("Message via WhatsApp",url,null)
      .then((ok)=>{
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(ok)
      },
      (err)=>{
         console.log("failed")
         console.log(err);
      })
  }
```

Url param is the internet url of the image. 
I try to downloading the image and calling whatsappShare function after with same result. Any Idea?

```
downloadFile(urlImage:string, idImage: string){

    const fileTransfer = new Transfer();
    let url = urlImage;
    let path: string;
    let name: string;

    name = idImage + ".gif"
    if(this.platform.is('android')){
      path = cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory
    }
    if(this.platform.is('ios')){
      path = cordova.file.tempDirectory;
    }
    fileTransfer.download(url, path + name).then((entry) => {
      console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
      console.log('ahora compartimos la imagen');
      this.whatsappShare(path + name);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Error descargando imagen");
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Me too, have you solved?